# PEG parser generator

Tags: python, parsing

I wrote a Python PEG parser generator that takes a grammar as a string, and returns a parser. The parser can parse its own syntax, and is feature complete with the original PEG paper, with some additions.

I'm looking for comments on the implementation itself, and the interface it uses. I also put in effort to make sure the implementation works on both Python 2.7 and Python 3.x, and would be interested in any things I overlooked.

There is no good syntax error reporting yet, but I already have an idea how to do this (by modifying `Failure` to contain context). But if there is some other ingenious solid way of reporting syntax errors, I'm interested.

This is the implementation:

```py
from __future__ import unicode_literals
import string
import sys

# We only use unicode in our parser, except for __repr__, which must return str.
if sys.version_info.major == 2:
    repr_str = lambda s: s.encode("utf-8")
    str = unicode
else:
    repr_str = lambda s: s

peg_grammar_src = r"""
#                        Parsing Expression Grammars
# Based on:        A Recognition-Based Syntactic Foundation
#                              - Bryan Ford
#
# Modified slightly to use equals sign, simpler character escapes and fixed
# "-" at end of character class. Added a fixed number of repeats (e.g. {3})
# and starting a definition with a semicolon ensures any matched strings
# are ignored.

# Hierarchical syntax
grammar    = spacing definition+ eof
definition = semicolon? identifier equals expression
expression = sequence (slash sequence)*
sequence   = prefix*
prefix     = (and / not)? suffix
suffix     = primary (question / star / plus / repeat)?
repeat     = open_brace integer close_brace
primary    = identifier !equals
           / open_paren expression close_paren
           / literal / class / dot

# Lexical syntax
integer     = [0-9]+
identifier  = ident_start ident_cont* spacing
ident_start = [a-zA-Z_]
ident_cont  = ident_start / [0-9]
literal     = ['] (!['] char)* ['] spacing
            / ["] (!["] char)* ["] spacing
class       = "[" (!"]" range)* "]" spacing
range       = char "-" !"]" char / char
char        = "\\" [nrt'"\[\]\\]
            / "\\x" [0-9a-fA-F]{2}
            / "\\u" [0-9a-fA-F]{4}
            / "\\U" [0-9a-fA-F]{8}
            / !"\\" .
semicolon   = ";" spacing
equals      = "=" spacing
slash       = "/" spacing
and         = "&" spacing
not         = "!" spacing
question    = "?" spacing
star        = "*" spacing
plus        = "+" spacing
open_paren  = "(" spacing
close_paren = ")" spacing
open_brace  = "{" spacing
close_brace = "}" spacing
dot         = "." spacing
; spacing   = (space / comment)*
comment     = "#" (!eol .)* eol
space       = " " / "\t" / eol
eol         = "\r\n" / "\n" / "\r"
eof         = !.
"""

class Failure(object): pass

class Val(object):
    """Val represents a value resulting from a grammar expression.

    If v is a Val object, str(v) returns the string as found in the source,
    v.v is the value, v.name is the name if the value resulted from a non-
    terminal, and v.ignore indicates that it's value is to be ignored for
    str().

    As a shorthand, you can index v directly, rather than having to write
    v.v[i] to index lists of results."""

    def __init__(self, v, name=None, ignore=False):
        self.name = name
        self.v = v
        self.ignore = ignore

    def __str__(self):
        if self.ignore: return ""
        if type(self.v) is str: return self.v
        return "".join(str(v) for v in self.v)

    if sys.version_info.major == 2:
        __unicode__ = __str__
        del __str__

    def __repr__(self):
        return repr_str("{}({!r})".format(type(self).__name__, self.v))

    def __getitem__(self, idx): return self.v[idx]
    def __len__(self): return len(self.v)

class AnyCharVal(Val): pass
class StringVal(Val): pass
class CharClassVal(Val): pass
class OptionalVal(Val): pass
class ZeroOrMoreVal(Val): pass
class OneOrMoreVal(Val): pass
class SequenceVal(Val): pass
class ChoiceVal(Val):
    def __init__(self, v, choice, name=None, ignore=False):
        super(ChoiceVal, self).__init__(v, name, ignore)
        self.choice = choice

class Expr(object):
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data

    def parse(self, s):
        m, i = self.match(s)
        if m is Failure or i != len(s): return None
        return m

    def __repr__(self):
        return repr_str("{}({!r})".format(type(self).__name__, self.data))

class AnyChar(Expr):
    def __init__(self): pass
    def __repr__(self): return repr_str("AnyChar()")
    def match(self, s, i=0):
        if i >= len(s): return Failure, i
        return AnyCharVal(s[i]), i + 1

class CharClass(Expr):
    def match(self, s, i=0):
        if i >= len(s) or s[i] not in self.data: return Failure, i
        return CharClassVal(s[i]), i + 1

class String(Expr):
    def match(self, s, i=0):
        ss = s[i:i+len(self.data)]
        if ss != self.data: return Failure, i
        return StringVal(ss), i + len(self.data)

class AndPredicate(Expr):
    def match(self, s, i=0):
        m, _ = self.data.match(s, i)
        return Failure if m is Failure else None, i

class NotPredicate(Expr):
    def match(self, s, i=0):
        m, _ = self.data.match(s, i)
        return Failure if m is not Failure else None, i

class Optional(Expr):
    def match(self, s, i=0):
        m, i = self.data.match(s, i)
        return OptionalVal([] if m is Failure else [m]), i

class ZeroOrMore(Expr):
    def match(self, s, i=0):
        l = []
        while True:
            m, i = self.data.match(s, i)
            if m is Failure: return ZeroOrMoreVal(l), i
            if m is not None: l.append(m)

class OneOrMore(Expr):
    def match(self, s, i=0):
        l = []
        m, i = self.data.match(s, i)
        if m is Failure: return Failure, i
        while True:
            if m is not None: l.append(m)
            m, i = self.data.match(s, i)
            if m is Failure: return OneOrMoreVal(l), i

class Sequence(Expr):
    def match(self, s, i=0):
        orig_i = i
        l = []
        for expr in self.data:
            m, i = expr.match(s, i)
            if m is Failure: return Failure, orig_i
            if m is not None:
                l.append(m)
        if len(l) > 1:
            return SequenceVal(l), i
        return l[0] if l else None, i

class Choice(Expr):
    def match(self, s, i=0):
        for choice, expr in enumerate(self.data):
            m, i = expr.match(s, i)
            if m is not Failure:
                return ChoiceVal(m, choice), i
        return Failure, i

class Nonterminal(Expr):
    def __init__(self, name, expr, ignore=False):
        self.name = name
        self.expr = expr
        self.ignore = ignore

    def match(self, s, i=0):
        m, i = self.expr.match(s, i)
        if m is not Failure:
            if m is not None:
                m.name = self.name
                m.ignore = self.ignore
            return m, i
        return Failure, i

    def __repr__(self):
        return repr_str("Nonterminal({!r}, {!r})".format(self.name, self.expr))

def compile_grammar(grammar):
    definitions = peg_grammar.parse(grammar)[1]
    identifiers = [str(d[1]) for d in definitions]
    if len(identifiers) > len(set(identifiers)):
        raise RuntimeError("duplicate definition")

    nts = {ident: Nonterminal(ident, None) for ident in identifiers}  # Forward declaration.
    for d in definitions:
        identifier, expr = str(d[1]), d[3]
        nts[identifier].expr = compile_expr(expr, nts)
        if d[0]: nts[identifier].ignore = True

    return nts[identifiers[0]]

def compile_expr(expr, nts):
    if not len(expr[1]):
        return compile_seq(expr[0], nts)
    return Choice([compile_seq(expr[0], nts)] + [compile_seq(s[1], nts) for s in expr[1]])

def compile_seq(seq, nts):
    if len(seq) == 0: return String("")
    if len(seq) == 1: return compile_prefix(seq[0], nts)
    return Sequence([compile_prefix(p, nts) for p in seq])

def compile_prefix(prefix, nts):
    predicate = {"&": AndPredicate,
                 "!": NotPredicate,
                  "": lambda s: s}[str(prefix[0])]
    return predicate(compile_suffix(prefix[1], nts))

def compile_suffix(suffix, nts):
    op = str(suffix[1])
    quantifier = {"?": Optional,
                  "*": ZeroOrMore,
                  "+": OneOrMore,
                  "{": lambda p: Sequence([p] * int(op[1:-1])),
                   "": lambda p: p}[op[:1]]
    return quantifier(compile_primary(suffix[0], nts))

def compile_primary(r, nts):
    if r.choice == 0:
        return nts[str(r)]
    elif r.choice == 1:
        return compile_expr(r[1], nts)
    elif r.choice == 2:
        return String("".join(char_to_str(ch) for ch in r[1]))
    elif r.choice == 3:
        return CharClass("".join(map(compile_char_range, r[1])))
    return AnyChar()

def compile_char_range(char_range):
    if char_range.choice == 0:
        start = ord(char_to_str(char_range[0]))
        stop = ord(char_to_str(char_range[2])) + 1
        return "".join(chr(c) for c in range(start, stop))
    elif char_range.choice == 1:
        return char_to_str(char_range.v)

def char_to_str(ch):
    if ch.choice == 0:  # Backslash.
        ch = str(ch[1])
        return {"n": "\n", "r": "\r", "t": "\t"}.get(ch, ch)
    elif ch.choice == 4:  # Literal.
        return str(ch)
    return chr(int(str(ch[1]), 16))  # Unicode escape.


def bootstrap_grammar():
    # Equivalent to peg_grammar_src, but directly expressed using primitives. For correctness
    # this grammar was semi-automatically generated from peg_grammar_src after the first
    # version was hand-written.
    eof         = NotPredicate(AnyChar())
    eol         = Choice([String("\r\n"), String("\n"), String("\r")])
    space       = Choice([String(" "), String("\t"), eol])
    comment     = Sequence([String("#"), ZeroOrMore(Sequence([NotPredicate(eol), AnyChar()])), eol])
    spacing     = Nonterminal("spacing", ZeroOrMore(Choice([space, comment])), ignore=True)
    dot         = Sequence([String("."), spacing])
    close_brace = Sequence([String("}"), spacing])
    open_brace  = Sequence([String("{"), spacing])
    close_paren = Sequence([String(")"), spacing])
    open_paren  = Sequence([String("("), spacing])
    plus        = Sequence([String("+"), spacing])
    star        = Sequence([String("*"), spacing])
    question    = Sequence([String("?"), spacing])
    not_        = Sequence([String("!"), spacing])
    and_        = Sequence([String("&"), spacing])
    slash       = Sequence([String("/"), spacing])
    equals      = Sequence([String("="), spacing])
    semicolon   = Sequence([String(";"), spacing])
    hexchar     = CharClass("0123456789abcdefABCDEF")
    char        = Choice([Sequence([String("\\"), CharClass("nrt'\"[]\\")]),
                          Sequence([String("\\x"), Sequence([hexchar] * 2)]),
                          Sequence([String("\\u"), Sequence([hexchar] * 4)]),
                          Sequence([String("\\U"), Sequence([hexchar] * 8)]),
                          Sequence([NotPredicate(String("\\")), AnyChar()])])
    range_      = Choice([Sequence([char, String("-"), NotPredicate(String("]")), char]), char])
    delim       = (lambda start, inner, stop:
                       Sequence([String(start),
                                 ZeroOrMore(Sequence([NotPredicate(String(stop)), inner])),
                                 String(stop), spacing]))
    class_      = delim("[", range_, "]")
    literal     = Choice([delim("'", char, "'"), delim('"', char, '"')])
    ident_start = CharClass(string.ascii_letters + "_")
    ident_cont  = Choice([ident_start, CharClass(string.digits)])
    identifier  = Sequence([ident_start, ZeroOrMore(ident_cont), spacing])
    integer     = OneOrMore(CharClass(string.digits))

    expression      = Nonterminal("expression", None) # Forward declaration, needed for recursion.
    primary         = Choice([Sequence([identifier, NotPredicate(equals)]),
                              Sequence([open_paren, expression, close_paren]),
                              literal, class_, dot])
    repeat          = Sequence([open_brace, integer, close_brace])
    suffix          = Sequence([primary, Optional(Choice([question, star, plus, repeat]))])
    prefix          = Sequence([Optional(Choice([and_, not_])), suffix])
    sequence        = ZeroOrMore(prefix)
    expression.expr = Sequence([sequence, ZeroOrMore(Sequence([slash, sequence]))])
    definition      = Sequence([Optional(semicolon), identifier, equals, expression])
    grammar         = Sequence([spacing, OneOrMore(definition), eof])
    return grammar

peg_grammar = bootstrap_grammar()
```

And this is an example parser using the above parser generator (in Python 3):

```py
grammar = compile_grammar(r"""
expr = factor ([+-] factor)*
factor = primary ([*/] primary)*
# The predicate is to make sure a number doesn't match ".".
number = &("."? [0-9]) [0-9]* ("." [0-9]*)?
primary = "(" expr ")" / number / "-" primary
""")

def eval_expr(expr):
    r = eval_factor(expr[0])
    for f in expr[1]:
        if str(f[0]) == "+": r += eval_factor(f[1])
        else:                r -= eval_factor(f[1])
    return r

def eval_factor(factor):
    r = eval_primary(factor[0])
    for p in factor[1]:
        if str(p[0]) == "*": r *= eval_primary(p[1])
        else:                r /= eval_primary(p[1])
    return r

def eval_primary(primary):
    if primary.choice == 0:   return eval_expr(primary[1])
    elif primary.choice == 1: return float(str(primary))
    else:                     return -eval_primary(primary[1])

def eval_str(s):
    return eval_expr(grammar.parse(s.replace(" ", "")))

print(eval_str(".5+3*5--(6.+5)/3"))
```